# How to join data from large data source with small data source on different server in SSIS in best way?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am having ERP data source having 16 million records and need to select only few thousand records but based on a data from different source ,where condition would have worked but the data to used in where condition is coming from a different source on a different server, the traditional approach is to use merge join which is very time consuming.
I need a approach without merge join or lookup column to make it faster.
Below is what I have done for syncing data from ERP to company's database [image]

The above package is for financial transactions and is being synced daily every morning to Company's DB since ERP data is read only.To sync 16 million records it takes me 30 mins with parllel tasks and table partitioning , however Finance Dept now wants to manually run the package when they wish , lets say he wishes only to sync 100 records of the ERP to  Company Db , if below solution is used it scans all 16 million records to get the required 100 records to sync, to give a use case 
Finance Department selects few ledgers in our company application(uses company db)company application has to run the package only for that Ledgers to get the updated Net Balance in company's application.So my approach was to store the ledgers that he selected in a table and join the table to ERP in SSIS package.
and go ahead like the daily morning sync(above apckage)

```
SELECT netbalance FROM ERP WHERE ledger in (SELECT ledgercode from MYSKM )
```

I wanted to achieve something like above but not possible since both ERP and MYSKM are on different servers

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your question what the issue is -- do you mean the ERP input has 16 million rows and you need to filter *these* to only a few thousand rows? In that case, consider importing the other source into a temp table on the same database and performing a `JOIN` (or `WHERE [NOT] EXISTS`) in SQL as the input query. If the other source also has millions of rows, there isn't really a fast solution -- both SQL Server and SSIS would have to do a lot of work in any case (but SQL Server tends to be much faster, as it is optimized for this, while SSIS is not).

Comment: We don't have a lot of information to go on. If ERP and SKM are on the same server, why not use a `JOIN` and one source?

Comment: Can you fill a permanent temp table on ERP from SKM and perform your operations all from ERP sql server?

Comment: ERP(Infor) and SKM(Company DB) are on a different server , i need to cut down the  size of the ERP Data  that is being synced

Comment: We cant create tables on ERP Server

Comment: How many rows are in SKM? Another option is to read the rows from there in a table and pass this as a table-valued parameter in a query (or, if creating table types is not possible either, as an XML or JSON value that you shred in the query, depending on your SQL Server version). You do not necessarily need to use the full row data either -- you can restrict it to what is most necessary to filter the data, then perform the full join in SSIS on the filtered data. (Also, even if creating tables inside databases is disallowed, a global temp table (`##table`) should still be possible.)

Comment: Can you provide some more concrete details/sample data about your problem? My ERP data looks like X. My SKM data looks like Y. How do you know how much ERP data to pull? What are the data types, sample values, etc

Comment: My first thought was "Use the SKM table to construct a query to send to the ERP table, use OpenQuery() to send the query to the ERP table for execution, and then process the results as needed".  Without table schema information, I can't be more specific.

Comment: Can you create a linked server on ERP to SKM?

Comment: How about construct SQL string? like you have a variable, and set \@Variable = (SELECT ledgerCode FROM MYSKM).join(","), and then pass this \@Variable to SELECT netbalance FROM ERP WHERE ledger in '"+\@Variable+"'